# Scope of JavaScript functions in server controls

Tags: javascript, asp.net, custom-server-controls, servercontrols

I have decided to learn how to create server controls because of the problems I was having with user controls. I wanted to be able to create JavaScript functions for my user controls so I could call userControl1.clientSideFunction(); You cant actually do this with user controls because the function would just get put into the page as clientSideFunction(); and not actually be attached to the user control. There are ways to accomplish this with a user control but it's not designed to allow for it. From my understanding server controls were designed to allow for this. I can't find very much information about it, does anyone know how to do this? Here is the basic outline of my control.

```
namespace ServerControl1
{
    public class Class1 : CompositeControl
    {
        private DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxButton btnTest;
        private DevExpress.Web.ASPxPopupControl.ASPxPopupControl popupTest;

        protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.Write("<h1>This is my control</h1>");      
        }

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            btnTest = new DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.ASPxButton();
            btnTest.Text = "wazzzup"; 

            popupTest = new DevExpress.Web.ASPxPopupControl.ASPxPopupControl();
            popupTest.Width = Unit.Pixel(500);
            popupTest.Height = Unit.Pixel(500);
            popupTest.Controls.Add(btnTest);
            popupTest.ShowOnPageLoad = true;
            Controls.Add(popupTest);                       
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/04/29/creating-custom-asp-net-server-controls-with-embedded-javascript.aspx

Edit:

You will need to create a client side version (embedded javascript class) of your control that has the properties and functions that you need/want. The client side javascript class should probably have a collection of references to child controls for easy access. It should also store a reference to the client side control itself. One way to do this would be to create a new instance of the client side class with a reference to the control and a list of child controls as parameters. The link above will show you how to embed the javascript class.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.